# PowerMock - stubbing a parent methodcall does not return stubbed value

Tags: java, junit, powermock, stubbing

Two classes. Parent: B. Child: A. A.method1() overrides B's.

```
public class B {
    protected boolean method1(){...};
}

public class A extends B {
    protected boolean method1(){
        boolean val = super.method1();
        ... //very short segment of logic that doesn't affect val.
        return val;
    }
}
```

Inside of my test class:

```
@Test
public void testA() {
    stub(method(B.class, "method1")).toReturn(true);
    assertTrue((Boolean)(Whitebox.invokeMethod(A.class, "method1")));
}
```

The assertion fails (it returns false). Am I missing something? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The methods, which you test are non static methods. You can stub non static methods for mock instances only, I think. So you cannot pass the Class Objects for stubbing.